# Using tmpl=component with SEF URL

Tags: component, templates, sef

I'm using the info found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_print_pop-up_functionality_to_a_component) to add a full screen option to a component. The code looks like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo Juri::getInstance().'&tmpl=component&return='.$this->return; ?>">
```

However, the link returns a 404 if SEF URLs are enabled. I also see this problem when I use a static, non-SEF link like this:

```
<a href="index.php?option=mycomponent&view=thisview&tmpl=component&return='.$this->return; ?>">
```

Is it possible to use the full screen / tmpl=component view with SEF URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try it with JRoute?

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=mycomponent&view=thisview&tmpl=component&return=' . $this->return); ?>">
```